# Choosing at least one of 3 different types

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose I had to choose 5 people from 8 engineers, 7 scientists and 6 mathematicians. How many ways can I choose at least one person from each profession?

By brute force total number of selection possible $n$:
$$n = \binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{3}+\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{3}\binom{6}{1}+\binom{8}{3}\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{1}+\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{2}\binom{6}{2}+\binom{8}{2}\binom{7}{2}\binom{6}{3}+\binom{8}{2}\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{2}=14140$$

Is there a more suitable approach to solving this problem? Moreover, can it be generalised?

Suppose I had to choose $n$ objects from $p$ distinguishable objects of one type, $q$ distinguishable objects of another type and $r$ distinguishable objects of the last type, given $p,q,r>n$. Then how many ways are there to choose $n$ people with at least one from each category?

How could I generalise this for more, say $m$, categories?

Comment: @Haris I have added an example. Through brute force, I get a much higher result than with the stars and bars, which would yield $\binom{4}{2}$, unless I have mistaken. Moreover, I think the problem with the stars and bars is that it assumes that the individual items are indistinguishable. However, in my case, they are distint, so the stars and bars would not work.

Comment: I assumed people "of one type" were indistinguishable. Perhaps not the most reasonable interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

There should be $p+q+r\choose n$$-$$p+q\choose n$$-$$p+r\choose n$$-$$q+r\choose n$$+$$p\choose n$$+$$q\choose n$$+$$r\choose n$ ways to choose $n$ from at least each category.

Using the principle of inclusion-exclusion (PIE), the total number of ways to choose $n$ people without any restrictions is $p+q+r\choose n$. When at least one type of occupation is missing, we subtract $p+q\choose n$, $p+r\choose n$, and$q+r\choose n$. Finally, we double-counted the cases where two types are missing. We add $p\choose n$$+$$q\choose n$$+$$r\choose n$.

Let's test our formula with your original example!

$21\choose 5$$-$$15\choose 5$$-$$14\choose 5$$-$$13\choose 5$$+$$8\choose 5$$+$$7\choose 5$$+$$6\choose 5$$=14140$ as desired.

I'm not sure if this is more suitable for you but this formula seems a lot simpler than using brute force. This can be expanded for $m$ categories as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ordinary generating functions, and find the coefficient of $x^5$ in the expansion of

$\left[\binom81x+\binom82x^2+\binom83x^3\right]\left[\binom71x + \binom72x^2+\binom73x^3\right]+\left[\binom61x+\binom62x^2 + \binom63x^3\right]$

which [evaluates](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=coefficient+x%5E5+in+%288x+%2B28x%5E2%2B56x%5E3%29%287x%2B21x%5E2%2B35x%5E3%29%286x%2B15x%5E2%2B20x%5E3%29) to the expected $14140$

Note that we have restricted the exponents to a maximum of $3$ in each factor because of the non-zero constraint for each type